# Running Mongodb on OSX Mavericks

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have installed MongoDB on OSX using Homebrew.

When I run:
mongo

Mongo starts but doesnt seem to be able to connect to the test database. This is what comes up:

> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3 
>   connecting to: test

Mongo doesn't then get any further.

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: Do you have a small `>` prompt after the "connecting to:" line? If so,  all is as expected; try typing `help` for a list of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you start the `mongod` process? `mongo` is just a client for connecting to the database. Checkout `brew info mongo` for several methods on running/starting the database itself.

Comment: Thanks -- I had to quit all the mongo and mongod processes and then restart mongod after creating and chowning the /data/db file...